# Как сохранить сайт, который загружается не сразу (рейтинг LiveJournal)

Tags: c#, .net

Мне нужно сохранить рейтинг(25 позиций), который открывается при входе на Livejournal.com, чтобы впоследствии парсить его при помощи HTMLAgilityPack. Попытался сделать так:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://www.livejournal.com", "d:\\tmp\\lj.txt");
```

Сохраненный файл не содержит самого рейтинга, ведь при входе через браузер рейтинг загружается не сразу. Есть какой-нибудь простой способ вытащить рейтинг оттуда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально неправильный подход. Ну откуда у людей берутся мысли типа "отпарсить HTML", когда правильное решение написано АРШИННЫМИ БУКВАМИ в справке самого ЖЖ?

Для особо одарённых: можно получать RSS топа.

Comment: Господин, растолкуйте, пожалуйста правильно решение для тупых. Про RSS знаю.
Полная задача заключается в следующем: программа (или служба) должна пару раз в сутки скачивать и сохранять топ25 ЖЖ. В воскресенье, я хочу почитать все записи которые попадали в топ25 за неделю (с нужными мне сортировками и выкидывание дубликатов).
p.s. могу работать только на c#

Comment: О, господин, ты ослепителен в своем величии. Не гневайся на убогого, но никакой ЖЖ-шной документации для разработчиков я не смог найти. Зато твоя идея с получением топа через RSS мне подходит, попробую класс SyndicationFeed. Хоть ты высокомерен и груб, но галочку тебе поставлю попозже думаю.

Comment: Отлично! Не забудь, о, падаван, соблюдать их bot policy, и, в особенности, посылать и принимать `If-Modified-Since/Last-Modified`. Как они это пишут здесь, например: http://www.livejournal.com/bots/ А как на самом деле - это к RFC...

Comment: Мастер, прости великодушно, но при попытке загрузить топ получаю exception " При выполнении синтаксического анализа значения DateTime в XML-документе произошла ошибка."

 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("h ttp://www.livejournal.com/top/rss");
 SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

Хотя при использовании rss юзера (http://tema.livejournal.com/data/rss) все работает нормально.

Comment: А что говорит `wget -S http://что-то_там` - первейший инструмент, который нужно освоить до любого языка программирования? Чем отличается полученный документ от других валидных RSS, полученных тем же способом?

Comment: Не серчай друг и успехов тебе.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет NHtmlUnit или его аналоги.

Comment: хотелось бы что-нибудь под c#. За наводку спасибо, ищу.

Comment: @Dork NHtmlUnit - под C#

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?